# Flutter WebView blob file download

Tags: javascript, flutter, webview

Im trying to download files like `.csv`, `.exe` etc... but i could'nt achieve it so,

Here is my code,

```
InAppWebView(
        initialUrl: '...',
        initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
          crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
              debuggingEnabled: true,
              useOnDownloadStart: true,
              javaScriptEnabled: true,
          ),
        ),
        //javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller = webViewController;
          },
          onLoadStop: (_controller ,url) async {
          await _loadData();

          _controller.evaluateJavascript(source:
"console.log(document.getElementById('field-lastname').value = '${data[Field.name]}' );"
+"console.log(document.getElementById('generate-btn').click());"

           );
          },

          onDownloadStart:(_controller,url) async{
            print("onDownloadStart $url");
            final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
                url: url,
                savedDir: (await getExternalStorageDirectory()).path,
            showNotification: true, // show download progress in status bar (for Android)
            openFileFromNotification: true,);
          },

      ),
```

The URL printed is like this one

onDownloadStart blob:https://example.com/a2a5316c-9290-4da7-8a2a-9f899861046a

Can someone help?

Comment: any luck with this? facing the same problem